# Logic gate biasing a BJT (again)

Tags: bjt, logic-gates, biasing

The following schematic shows a PNP BJT driven by the output of a logic gate. When the logic gate output is high the transistor must be off, and only be activated when the logic goes low.

The problem is that while the capacitor is charging the base voltage exceeds the reverse Vbe breakdown which is around 5 V. Is there any solution?

[image]

Comment: How about a diode on the base of the transistor?

Comment: What response are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To prevent charging of the cap when logic connected to base goes low.

Comment: If the capacitor is completely charged, it holds 0.7mJ of energy.  Those are (mostly) discharged with a peak power of several Watts.  The thermal inertia of Q1 needs to be large enough to contain that; on a continuing basis, power is supplied through R3 and is not an issue for longterm dissipation.  The RC time constant is 10s.  The low-to-high transition will be one long smear and might keep the subsequent logic at unspecified levels for extended amounts of time.  Maybe think about a Schmitt-trigger here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution?

It looks like the transistor is there to forcibly discharge the capacitor so, swap to an NPN and put emitter to ground and invert the logic signal to the base resistor: -

[image]

Benefit - the capacitor will be much more fully discharged to 0 volts as opposed to about 0.7 volts with the PNP circuit.

Adding a diode in parallel with the base - emitter junction of the PNP will indeed protect it but, you'll also immediately charge the capacitor via this diode instead of it being charged by the 1 Mohm resistor.

Comment: What about putting a diode in series with R1? inverting signals require re-design of logic circuit. It would be difficult.

Comment: Also, using the voltage divider will increase quiesient current. The circuit was designed to have low quiescent current.

Comment: Well, if you are not too bothered that using a PNP emitter follower won't accurately discharge the capacitor to a definite level (0 volts) and that this level will be temperature dependent then a diode in series would work providing the leakage current of the diode is always less than the leakage current of the base emitter junction. Having said that, the worst that will happen is noise (given that diode leakage will be in the uA region anyway).

Comment: You don't need \$R_G\$ for this to work - it's just a picture from the web. Anyway, you could use an N channel MOSFET instead if base current represented an issue.

Comment: What's RG? wouldn't the N mosfet be on when the voltage at gate is logic high?

Comment: typo - I meant to say \$R_0\$. Yes, you have to invert the logic as I said in my answer.

Comment: Other issue with both this circuit and the OPs original is that the current thru the transistor will be LARGE when transistor turns on with a fully charged capacitor.

Comment: Yes, It needs a resistor on the collector side in my diagram or on the emitter side in the Andy's circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka the reverse leakage of 1N4148 is max 25nA for 20V. Since the device never gets hot, I am sure it's much lower than 25nA.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap out the transistor and base resistor for a [CD4007](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4007ub.pdf?ts=1595964284820&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4007UB%253FkeyMatch%253DCD4007%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything) chip:

[image]

This will reset the capacitor to about 5mV, and draws only leakage power, other than the 8.5uA through the 1M resistor when the capacitor is being reset, and the unavoidable charging current.

An even better circuit that resets the capacitor to microvolts and draws no power (other than leakage) while the capacitor is being discharged is shown below. There are still 2 free MOSFETs in the 4007 that could be used for an inverter or something else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You transistor is connected with the collector tied to ground, meaning that the transistor is never really "on". In this configuration, the emitter follows the base in potential, a linear relationship very different from "on/off". Hence the name "[emitter follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector)".

The easiest way to prevent a strongly reverse-biased base-emitter junction is with a diode, but in your emitter follower setup, that might be a problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f03qqn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Diode D1 prevents base current from flowing when the base-emitter junction is reverse biased. However, when the input is \$V_{IN}=0V\$, ideally you would like C1 to discharge completely, so that \$V_{OUT}=0V\$, but that won't happen. You have the diode drop of D1, and another diode drop across the base-emitter junction, totalling 1.2V or so, and \$V_{OUT}\$ will never fall below +1.2V.

Compare the above with a "[common emitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter)" arrangement, which in this application will exhibit a much more digital "on/off" behaviour". Note that I'm using an NPN transistor here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRuUMF.png)</sup>

The emitter is tied to ground, so the base-emitter junction will never be reverse biased. Since the emitter is no longer "following" the base in potential, the transistor will be fully "on" when \$V_{IN} >> 0.7V\$.

This means that the capacitor will discharge, and \$V_{OUT}\$ will fall to near-zero, when the digital input is *high*; in other words, it inverts, which may or may not be a problem for you.

There's still one other improvement to be made. When Q1 is fully on, it will discharge C1 with almost unimpeded current, which could over-stress or even damage the transistor. It's better to limit discharge current to something the transistor will be comfortable with, say 100mA, using R2 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvpLX8.png)</sup>

You'll notice that the capacitor may still never discharge all the way to 0V, since even a fully saturated transistor will always have \$V_{CE} > 0V\$. A MOSFET will perform much better in this respect:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwccWk.png)</sup>